# Return a string in a while loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, while-loop, stringbuilder

Here, I want to avoid using the line `return "";` and instead return all of the values I output with `System.out.println();`

I have tried using a `StringBuilder` method, but this outputs nothing when I run my test program. I am guessing that `StringBuilder` must work differently in a `while` loop, but I can't find how!

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!

```
public String toString(){
    int topLine = size;
    int topCurrentLine = size;
    int bottomLine = 1;
    int bottomCurrentLine = size;

    while(topCurrentLine<=size){
        topCurrentLine= (size-topLine)+1;

        if (topCurrentLine<=size){
            for (int i = 0; i < (topCurrentLine-1); ++i){
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            System.out.print(starMinusLine(getSandInLine(topLine), ((2*topLine-1)-getSandInLine(topLine)),false));

            for (int i = 0; i < (topCurrentLine-1); ++i){
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            topLine = topLine -1;

            System.out.print("\n");
        }       
    }

    while(bottomCurrentLine>1){         
        bottomCurrentLine= (size-bottomLine)+1;

        for (int i = 0; i < (bottomCurrentLine-1); ++i){
            System.out.print(".");
        }

        System.out.print(starMinusLine(getSandInLine(bottomLine), ((2*bottomLine-1)-getSandInLine(bottomLine))));

        for (int i = 0; i < (bottomCurrentLine-1); ++i){
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        bottomLine = bottomLine +1;

        System.out.print("\n");     
    }

    return "";      
}
```

Here is my attempt with StringBuilder:

```
public String toString(){ 
    int topLine = size;
    int topCurrentLine = size;
    int bottomLine = 1;
    int bottomCurrentLine = size;

    StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();

    while(topCurrentLine<=size) {
        topCurrentLine= (size-topLine)+1;

        if (topCurrentLine<=size){
            for (int i = 0; i < (topCurrentLine-1); ++i){
                y.append(".");
            }

            y.append(starMinusLine(getSandInLine(topLine), ((2*topLine-1)-getSandInLine(topLine)),false));

            for (int i = 0; i < (topCurrentLine-1); ++i){
                y.append(".");
            }
            topLine = topLine -1;

            y.append("\n");
        }

    }

    while(bottomCurrentLine > 1) {      
        bottomCurrentLine= (size-bottomLine)+1;

        for (int i = 0; i < (bottomCurrentLine-1); ++i){
            y.append(".");
        }

        y.append(starMinusLine(getSandInLine(bottomLine), ((2*bottomLine-1)-getSandInLine(bottomLine))));

        for (int i = 0; i < (bottomCurrentLine-1); ++i){
            y.append(".");
        }
        bottomLine = bottomLine +1;

        y.append("\n");
    }

    return y.toString();
}
```

Comment: No, `StringBuilder` doesn't work any differently in a while loop. But the code you've posted doesn't include a `StringBuilder` at all, so we can't tell what you're doing wrong. Also, it would *really* help if you'd format your code clearly - it's very hard to read at the moment. Use spaces rather than tabs, and ideally reduce your code to a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints for more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for my code format! I'm just starting out and it's hard to get all my ideas together, never mind formatting! I've put my attempt with StringBuilder in the question

Comment: Looks fine, probably the problem is with how you _use_ this method. Wild guess: Your previous method printed directly to console, now the method is returning what was previously printed, but you still have to print it. In the code invoking the method, change `toString()` to `System.out.println(toString())`

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for explaining that! The answer section did provide the answer, but your explanation was useful! I was just getting confused as I thought the return would also print to console! Guess I still have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply print toString.  Just before

```
return y.toString();
```

add

```
System.out.println(y.toString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A StringBuilder can perfectly used in a while loop. Here is an example:

```
public String toString() {
    int size = 10;
    int current = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("All values:");
    while (current <= size) {
        sb.append("\ncurrent = " + current);
        current++;
    }

    sb.toString();
}
```

The String returned by this method is:

```
All values:
current = 0
current = 1
current = 2
current = 3
current = 4
current = 5
current = 6
current = 7
current = 8
current = 9
current = 10
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

create a  List object and pass it to your function toString(List yourlist).
In your toString(List yourlist) function add the strings you required to yourList.
You don't need to return the list.